# How to find specific object in node js

Tags: node.js, nodes

So I have run my code and here is the output

```
{ data:
   { cards:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ]
```

Then I run these

```
const getdata = data.cards[0]
```

and the result is

> ```
> Tester I'm the value you looking for
> ```

Problem is, these object is always changed.

I don't know where the object I want to looking for. They can be on cards[0] or cards[1] or cards[2] etc.

Because when I try to run same code:

```
const getdata = data.cards[0]
```

The result sometimes will different, they can be:

> Sorry, this is not value you looking for

So. Is it possible to find spesific object with value or something like that?

The value I'm looking for is exactly on these

```
data.cards[????].content.actions[0].deep_link
```

The outpot will be:

> Im the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `find` or `findIndex` on the `data.cards` array, like this:

To return the object:

```
const found = data.cards.find( d => d.content.actions[0].deep_link === 'YOUR_VALUE' )
```

To return the index:

```
const foundIndex = data.cards.findIndex( d => d.content.actions[0].deep_link === 'YOUR_VALUE' )
```

Where `d` represents each element in the array. Then, you need to make your validation and if it returns `true`; `find` or `findIndex` will return the object or index; on the other hand, if your returns `false`; the function will move on on the next element of the array.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I will try it, hope it will works perfectly. Again thank you so much. Will let you know if these works.

Comment: do you add the function `find` to the object?

Comment: @nnfans you use it on an array, in my example an array of objects, but it could be an array of any type of data.